screenshot valuebox, leaflet plot, ggplotly in one image from a R shiny app
I want to screenshot two value boxes, one leaflet plot and one ggplotly in the exact orientation represented in the following UI. I have watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsd81mnxtNs&t=569s about screenshot multiple plots at the same time by adding div() to include multiple plotlyoutput. However, when I do that, the plot downloaded is not viewable and I think it is due to the column() I have in my UI. Here is the section of UI code that I want to have a downloadable screenshot:

    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {height: 160px}"))),
        valueBoxOutput("trend_box", width = 6),
        valueBoxOutput("level_box", width = 6)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        div(id = "mainpageplot",
            column(
              6,
              leafletOutput("heatmap_region", height = "520px")
            ),
            column(
              6,
              plotlyOutput(outputId = "wwplot", height = "600px")
            )
        )
      )
    )

So I want to one valuebox at the top right, another valuebox at the top left, leaflet map at the bottom left and the plotly at the bottom right. I want to screenshot all fours in one image in this orientation
